# How to make Expanded gridview in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem with GridView widget in the bottom of the screen I have a GridView inside Scroll with Vertical Direction so I hade this problem :
"A RenderFlex overflowed by 9.3 pixels on the bottom"

my code :

```
        SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  child: GridView.count(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    primary: false,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: LightColor.background,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                          boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                            BoxShadow(
                                color: Color(0xfff8f8f8),
                                blurRadius: 15,
                                spreadRadius: 10),
                          ],
                        ),
                        child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                          child: Stack(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  // SizedBox(height: 5),

                                  Container(
                                    width: 100,
                                    height: 100,
                                    child: Stack(
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        CircleAvatar(
                                          radius: 40,
                                          backgroundColor:
                                              LightColor.orange.withAlpha(40),
                                        ),
                                        Image.network(
                                            "https://assets.swappie.com/iPhone-11-Pro-midnight-green-back.png")
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(child: Text("Informatique")),
                                  Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                        "Sony PS4 + Controller jdjjedjdjjfr hjhhjjhhjhj hjhjhbbhbh , hhhh "),
                                  ),

                                  Text("Brdo,Tunis"),
                                  Text("1200 DT")
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

Picture from my app :

[image: Picture]

and I want to make like this :

[image: Like this]

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you

```
  Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: GridView.builder(
        itemCount: 10, //use your length here
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),

        shrinkWrap: true,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Image.network(
                    'https://assets.swappie.com/iPhone-11-Pro-midnight-green-back.png',
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Informatique',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                    "Sony PS4 + Controller jdjjedjdjjfr hjhhjjhhjhj hjhjhbbhbh , hhhh "),
                Text("Brdo,Tunis"),
                Text("1200 DT"),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
```

Your Result -> [image]